# jquery .delegate() access text from selector

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic list that performs a function that varies based on its text. Because the list elements are appended, I need to use the `delegate()` function, however I'm not sure how to access each specific text for each selector.

`this` refers to the object that `delegate()` operates on, not the selector that received the event. `li` refers to only the first `li` element. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
$('#rooms').delegate('li', 'click', function(){
    console.log($('li').text());
    var index = $('li').text().indexOf(":");
    location.href = "http://localhost:3000/chat/" + $('li').text().substring(0, index);
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: You can use `$('#rooms').on('click', 'li', function() {` for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of `delegated` has been deprecated for `on()`. This method then allows you  to access the instance of the element that raised the event using the `this` keyword within the event handler. Try this:

```js
$('#rooms').on('click', 'li', function(){
    var $li = $(this);
    console.log($li.text());
    var index = $li.text().indexOf(":");
    //location.href = "http://localhost:3000/chat/" + $li.text().substring(0, index);
    var location = "http://localhost:3000/chat/" + $li.text().substring(0, index);
    alert(location);
});

$('<li />', { text: 'foo:bar' }).appendTo('#rooms');
$('<li />', { text: 'buzz:bizz' }).appendTo('#rooms');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="rooms"></ul>
```

Comment: @Nicolas - just to give you another push in the right direction towards code cleanup, don't forget to make a variable for `$(this)` so you aren't recalling the jQuery function every time

Comment: Changed to using .on() but 'this' is still grabbing the text of #rooms, not the li element.

Comment: @NicolasPeckman can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net as it should reference the clicked element.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel thanks for the tip, so just something like `var something = $(this);` ?

Comment: Exactly! A general convention is to use `var $this = $(this);` just for sake of clarity and readibility

Comment: @NicolasPeckman I added a working example to my answer for you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for the working example, inserting it made the code work fine! I was handeling 'this' wrong which is pretty embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're getting, but when i do this, `this` *is* the clicked element. Your code as posted should work fine.

However, i recommend [switching to `.on()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783878/3187556) anyways.

```js
$('#rooms').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
  $("#output").text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="rooms">
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>def</li>
  <li>ghi</li>
</ul>
<div id="output"></div>
```